# Unable to get read write permissions on internal hard drives

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive

I recently just installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my pc. I have three drives, my main internal SSD (which ubuntu is installed on), a secondary SSD, and an HDD. The filesystem on the primary SSD is fine, everything works like it is supposed to. However, on the other two hard drives, I am unable to get read/write permission. On the HDD, I was able to remount the drive with read write, and it appeared that I could delete files, however I soon found out that any deleted or edited files were restored to normal upon navigating out of that directory and back in. The HDD is still formatted in NFTS, but I decided to format the secondary SSD as ext4, and I have the same issues with it. I'm quite new to linux, so I apologize if anything I am doing is off, as I'm not too familiar with permissions and filesystems yet. It is not a hardware issue, as all the drives are able to be mounted, just not with any read/write permissions. I've run `sudo blkid` and all the drives and partitions appear to be correct and not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive was mounted as root, your regular user probably doesn't have permission to do anything because the mounted directory is owned by the user root and group root.

You can run below to see who owns control of the mounted drive

```
ls -la
```

To change permissions to your user to be able to utilise the drive, substitute below username and groupname as your username you set and the /directory as folder your drive is mounted too.

```
sudo chown -R username:groupname /directory
```

If you still have problems accessing the drive to add/remove files you may need to set permissions of the files and directories as well.